# Ext.Net RadioGroup CheckedItems is always null

Tags: asp.net, .net, extjs, ext.net

I'm seeing strange behaviour from Ext.Net 2.0: RadioGroup.CheckedItems is always zero in my change handler callback. In my code below RadioGroup1.CheckedItems is ALWAYS zero after checking. What am I doing wrong / how can I solve this?

```
[DirectMethod]
public void TxtVisibility()
{
    foreach (var item in RadioGroup1.CheckedItems)
    {
        if (item.ID == "rdHourly")
        {
            txtPerHour.Hidden = false;
            txtAtTime.Hidden = true;
        }
        else if (item.ID == "rdAtHourly")
        {
            txtPerHour.Hidden = true;
            txtAtTime.Hidden = false;
        }
    }  
}
```

My calling code:

```
<ext:RadioGroup ID="RadioGroup1" 
                runat="server" 
                FieldLabel="" 
                ColumnsNumber="1">
    <Items>
        <ext:Radio ID="rdHourly" FieldLabel="IsEveryPerHour"
                   Name="IsEveryPerHour" runat="server"
                   BoxLabel="Per Hour(s)" Padding="10">
        </ext:Radio>
        <ext:Radio ID="rdAtHourly" FieldLabel="IsAtHour"
                   Name="IsAtHour" runat="server"
                   BoxLabel="At" Padding="10">
       </ext:Radio>
    </Items>
    <Listeners>
         <Change Handler="App.direct.TxtVisibility();" ></Change>
    </Listeners>
</ext:RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason, please don't remove the code from your question.  That makes it useless to future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered this exact same question on the Ext.NET forums, then came over to Stack to see what's new today... and found this question.

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?18364

You might need to wait for the next Ext.NET v2 release. Your sample appears to be working fine with the latest source. There's a complete working example at the link above.